# Dual boot issues: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot

I have an assembled desktop with a Gigabyte Motherboard (H410M H V2) which came with Windows 10 preinstalled. I installed Ubuntu 20.04, the latest LTS version, and when I restart the grub is not coming and the PC straightaway boots into windows. Before installation, I disabled the legacy mode in UEFI firmware, and installed ubuntu from the live-usb that is compatible with the UEFI mode. After installation, the grub did not appear and again from a live-usb I booted into ubuntu and then using efibootmgr, I changed the boot order so that Ubuntu comes first. But, this did not make any improvement and grub still does not appear and the PC straightaway boot into windows. So I tried running the boot-repair from live-usb.

The following is the URL for the boot-repair summary report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZCkQbnnNHK/

The fast boot in Windows is already disabled. I tried changing the boot order in the UEFI settings of the Windows. But there only Windows 10 is getting listed and Ubuntu is not shown

Any support in this regard is highly appreciated.

An Update:
After doing a boot-repair run, I restarted the PC and then the grub came. I opted ubuntu and it boot into the OS. Again I gave a restart and checked the boot order and this is how it looked like:
[Check Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpt0b.jpg)

Ubutnu comes as the first option, which is exactly what I want. Then again I rebooted the  PC and selected windows. This time also everything went normal. Now the third time when I rebooted, the grub went missing and I straight away booted into windows. This time when I checked the bios the following is how it looked like:
[Check Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DtU6.jpg)

Ubuntu is missing from the boot option priority list.
Can someone help.

Comment: You need to remove a ton of this useless info so the question can be read such as the out put from unknown bootloader and someones repair suggestion.

Comment: And sometimes efibootmgr can't change the order in some hardware. You should check it directly in UEFI > Boot.

Comment: Boot-Repair recommends you post just the link to the summary report it creates in pastebin. Posting it directly loses formatting and makes it difficult to review. Remove it above & post link. Re-run report if needed. HP in particular only seems to recognize UEFI boot order changes if made inside UEFI settings (not UEFI boot menu).

Comment: Have you disabled fast start-up in Windows? That seems to me to be the most likely issue.

Comment: The following is the URL for the boot-repair summary report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZCkQbnnNHK/     The fast boot in Windows is already disabled. I tried changing the boot order in the UEFI settings of the Windows. But there only Windows 10 is getting listed and Ubuntu is not shown

Comment: UEFI is the motherboard's firmware, the new and improved one that replace the old BIOS many years ago. There's where you need to change the boot order, not from Windows, there's no such thing as "the UEFI settings of the Windows" (???)

Answer (score 0):

1. To change preset boot option I used F5 and F6 as described by the system (HP Laptop-15S-Du3xxx)
2. On inserting Flash drive with UBUNTU image I used F12 once it displayed momentarily HP logo.